# How to find the Min and Max value based on another column?

Tags: r

My input table is given below,

```
    +------+------------------+
    | Name |     Datetime     | 
    +------+------------------+
    | ABC  |  26-01-2019 4:55 |  
    | ABC  |  26-01-2019 4:35 |  
    | ABC  |  26-01-2019 5:00 |  
    | XYZ  |  26-01-2019 2:50 |  
    | XYZ  |  26-01-2019 4:00 |  
    | XYZ  |  26-01-2019 4:59 | 
    +------+------------------+
```

From the above table I wanted to find the min and max value of 'DateTime' based on 'Name' while rejecting in between 'DataTime' information, and create another column automatically if that person is early or late admitted using R Studio as given below,

```
    +------+------------------+--------+
    | Name |     Datetime     |  Col3  |  
    +------+------------------+--------+
    | ABC  |  26-01-2019 4:35 |  Early |  
    | ABC  |  26-01-2019 5:00 |  Late  |  
    | XYZ  |  26-01-2019 2:50 |  Early |  
    | XYZ  |  26-01-2019 4:59 |  Late  |  
    +------+------------------+--------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Split your datetime column and groupby-summarise. However, what do Early and Late mean and how do they relate to min and max?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, one way would be to convert `DateTime` column to `POSIXct`, `arrange` by `Datetime` and select 1st and last row  (min and max) in each group and add a new column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Datetime = as.POSIXct(Datetime, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  arrange(Datetime) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  slice(c(1L, n())) %>%
  mutate(Col3 = c("Early", "Late"))

#  Name  Datetime            Col3 
#  <fct> <dttm>              <chr>
#1 ABC   2019-01-26 04:35:00 Early
#2 ABC   2019-01-26 05:00:00 Late 
#3 XYZ   2019-01-26 02:50:00 Early
#4 XYZ   2019-01-26 04:59:00 Late
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option,

```
transform(stack(data.frame(
          do.call(cbind, 
              tapply(as.POSIXct(dd$Datetime, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'), dd$Name, function(i)
                  as.character(c(min(i), max(i))))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)), 
         col3 = c('Early', 'Late'))

#               values ind  col3
#1 2019-01-26 04:35:00 ABC Early
#2 2019-01-26 05:00:00 ABC  Late
#3 2019-01-26 02:50:00 XYZ Early
#4 2019-01-26 04:59:00 XYZ  Late
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
     arrange(dmy_hm(Datetime)) %>%
     group_by(Name) %>%
     filter(row_number() %in% c(1, n())) %>%
     mutate(Col3 = c("Early", "Late"))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Name [2]
#  Name  Datetime        Col3 
#  <chr> <chr>           <chr>
#1 XYZ   26-01-2019 2:50 Early
#2 ABC   26-01-2019 4:35 Early
#3 XYZ   26-01-2019 4:59 Late 
#4 ABC   26-01-2019 5:00 Late
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ"
), Datetime = c("26-01-2019 4:55", "26-01-2019 4:35", "26-01-2019 5:00", 
"26-01-2019 2:50", "26-01-2019 4:00", "26-01-2019 4:59")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```